# Is angular momentum conserved in all possible axis of rotation (give no external torque)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws

If you have an object maintaining circular motion then would the angular momentum be conserved along possible axes?

More elaborately: pick an axis on the circumference, one in the center, and one outside the circle. The result of all three is not the same.

Comment: can you think of an axis that causes trouble?

Comment: say the axis is normal to the plane of rotation and is on the circumfrence or if it is in the plane but outside the circle? would L be conserved in all those frames

Comment: On 2nd thought, pick a point, not an axis. Angular momentum is defined as $\vec r \times \vec p$ relative to a point...hint: as is torque $\vec \tau = \vec r \times \vec F$

Comment: weird now it seems only inside the circle that it is conserved  ... why is this?

Comment: I think any origin that is on the axis of the orbit works...but yes, it is a problem that is not addressed when these quantities are introduced, and that's because they're actually more complicated geometric objects that just "look like vectors" most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So circular motion works out well if everything references the center of the circle. If the momentum of the mass is $\vec p$, at radius $\vec r$ then:

$$ \vec L = \vec r \times \vec p$$

is a constant of motion:

$$\dot{\vec L} = (\dot{\vec r}\times\vec p) + (\vec r \times \dot{\vec p}) = 0 + 0.$$

The 1st one is zero because both $\dot{\vec r}$ and $\vec p$ are proportional to $\vec v$; the 2nd is zero because the radius is parallel to the force $\dot{\vec p}$.

The whole thing goes "wrong" when the central point is not $\vec 0$, the center of the circle. A qualitative analysis indicates the angular momentum oscillates (if the origin is moved to a point on the circle, it *must* be zero at that point)...what gives?

If we move it to $\vec a$:

$$ \vec L = (\vec r - \vec a) \times \vec p $$

$$ \dot{\vec L} = \frac{d}{dt}[(\vec r - \vec a)\times \vec p]=-\frac{d}{dt}[\vec a \times \vec p]$$

Since $\vec a$ is fixed:

$$ \dot{\vec L} = \vec a \times \dot{\vec p} = \vec{\tau}$$

So yes, there is a coordinate dependent oscillatory amplitude (and bias) added to what we would nominally call "the angular momentum", but at least the oscillatory part is explained by a coordinate dependent torque that conforms to our definition of torque and rate of change of angular momentum.

In summary: the radial centripetal force applies a coordinate dependent torque that accounts for the position dependent angular momentum.

In some circles, the fact that these quantities depend on choice of origin is why they are called "pseudo-vectors": they rotate like vectors by don't translate like them. This is related to the fact that they are axial-vectors, which rotate like vector but under reflection, do not change sign like true vectors... and that, is because they're really the 3 antisymmetric components of a rank-2 tensor (so when we say "$z$ component of an (axial)vector", we really mean "$xy$ component of a tensor minus the $yx$ component").

Comment: Can you explain this bias thing again physically?