# Angular momentum conservation along translating axis of rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws

Say you have a cylinder rolling on the ground, then could we take any possible axis as it's axis of rotation? Could we take as an axis parallel to the central axis of cylinder? what about one perpendicular to the floor which it is rolling around and passing thru center?

In my school we were only taught to take inertia along x,y and z axes and hence the confusion

Also, how would computing inertia look like when the r term in the inertia integral is a function of time? i.e:

$$ I = \int (r(t))^2 dm$$

This quesiton is different from this one:
[Is angular momentum conserved in all possible axis of rotation (give no external torque)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/545841/is-angular-momentum-conserved-in-all-possible-axis-of-rotation-give-no-external)

Because there I got an answer in reference to a stationary frame and here I'm asking for moving frame of reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be specific about what point or axis you are taking your angular momentum about.

You must remember that the equation
$$
{\boldsymbol \tau}= \frac{d{\bf L}}{dt}
$$ 
is not generally true.

Here 
$$
\tau= \sum_i ({\bf r}_i- {\bf R})\times {\bf F}_i
$$
is the torque about point ${\bf R}$ and 
$$
{\bf L} =\sum_i ({\bf r}_i- {\bf R)}\times m_i \dot {\bf r}_i
$$
is the angular momentum about ${\bf R}$ .

Applied torque only equals  the rate of change of angular momentum   when
$$
\dot {\bf R}\times \sum_i m_i \dot {\bf r}_i=0.
$$

The usual cases of this are if ${\bf R}$ satisfies one these consditions:

1) ${\bf R}$ is stationary

2) ${\bf R}$ is the center of mass

3) $\dot {\bf R}$ is parallel to the velocity of the center of mass

Comment: Just for reference, what is always true is $$\boldsymbol{\tau}_{A}=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{L}_{A}+\dot{\boldsymbol{r}}_{A}\times\boldsymbol{p} $$ for some arbitrary point _A_, where $\boldsymbol{p}$ is linear momentum.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't because after the bounce the direction of rotation must switch in order to maintain pure rolling.

To be precise, if there is *any* friction with the colliding object, then there will be a vertical frictional impulse acting on the body at the same time as the colliding impulse.

This frictional impulse will slow down or reverse the direction of rotation of the cylinder. Hence the angular momentum changes.

Even so, since the cylinder is rolling, it means there is friction to the ground, so after the bounce, the direction of rotation will need to change, and so does angular momentum.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the ground and the surfaces of the colliding cylinders are frictionless, angular momentum will be conserved. This is because during the collision, the only new force would be the normal force between the two cylinders, which would pass through the center of the colliding cylinder and thus the torque generated by it will be zero.

In case there's friction on the ground, then until the collision, the angular momentum will be perfectly conserved about the axis (assuming pure rolling with a constant velocity). But after the collision, friction force would start acting and thus would generate a torque about the center. Similarly, if there's friction between the colliding cylinders, then also the nagilar momentum will change due to momentary torque of this friction whe the cylinders collide.

Since you are using an axis passing throught the center of mass, thus only the angular velocity is responsible for the angular momentum.

$$\mathbf L=I\boldsymbol{\omega}$$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the body. So if the angular velocity changes, then the angular momentum will change. This approach can also be effectively used to check whether angular momentum is conserved or not.