# Point about which angular momentum is to be conserved

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, torque

In the question shown, why can i only get the correct answer by assuming conservation of angular momentum about **the point of contact P**.I get the wrong answer for angular velocity of the rolling cylinder if I conserve the angular momentum of the system about

1.The center of mass of the cylinder

or

2.Say a point at the top edge of the cylinder where the bullet gets embedded

..why is this happening ? [image]is it because there is a frictional impulse at the base of the cylinder ?

Comment: Hi Amy, we prefer not to have posts use images that include text. Could you please type out the text instead so it can be indexed by search engines? For formulas, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136).

Comment: @David Z -okay :) will do that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Angular momentum of a system is only conserved about an axis if all the external forces are passing through the said axis (because then no forces produce any torque about the said axis).

In your example, you're considering the bullet + cylinder as your system. The forces in the scenario are the forces between the bullet and the cylinder and the friction force from the ground. Only the friction force from the ground is an external force. Now think about which axis this force passes through (and thus won't produce any torque about it) and which axis it is not passing through (and thus *will* produce a torque about it leading to non-conservation of momentum about that axis). :)

Comment: I anwered esentially this question only a few days ago! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/549102/angular-momentum-conservation-along-translating-axis-of-rotation/549131#549131.   Hope that answer is useful  for  what you want.

Comment: @mike stone:yes i just read that thread including your answer..thank you.my doubt is resolved now :)

Comment: @Dvij.D.C -yes thank you, i was just unclear about the frictional impulse..:)