# Can the Torque equation $\tau=I\alpha$ only be applied on the center of mass of a body?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

So, my book says that the torque equation can only be applied on the center of mass of a body? Is it true? What if the COM is not passing through the axis of rotation and we are asked to find the $\alpha$ of the body? Please help, I'm really confused and I need to clear up these basics and concepts!

Comment: Read [this excellent reference](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/mechanical-systems/mm-dam/documents/Notes/Dynamics_LectureNotes.pdf#page=78) on this subject starting from section 3.2, which develops all the equations from first principles.

Answer (score 5):

> So, my book says that the torque equation can only be applied on the
> center of mass of a body

No, it's not true at all. Torque can be applied to *ANY part of a body*.

Think e.g. a wrench gripping a bolt or the friction force (tire to floor) on a wheel.

Incidentally, is that really what your book says? **Because if so, it's a very bad book...**

> What if the COM is not passing through the axis of rotation and we are
> asked to find the $\alpha$ of the body?

A body (object) can rotate about **ANY axis**, think e.g. the moon about the Earth or a door about its hinges.

$$\boxed{\Sigma\tau=I\alpha}\tag{1}$$

means if the (net)torque about **some axis** is $\tau$ and $I$ is the MoI about the same axis then the *angular acceleration $\alpha$* about that axis will be given by $(1)$, in accordance with $\text{N2L}$.

Comment: i think you got it wrong, my books meant the equation can only be applied at the com, it didn't say that torque can only be applied at the COM.

Comment: @Vega This is also not true. If the object is hinged, for instance, then the rotation will happen about an axis through the hinge point. Such as with a door. This equation $$\sum \tau=I\alpha$$does describe the rotation that happens. The moment-of-inertia $I$ just must be that which is related to this particular rotation axis. Maybe your hook is referring to an $I$ related to a rotation axis through the centre-of-mass? Would you mind quoting it exactly?

Comment: @Vega Like Steeven, I feel you may be misquoting the book. Words really matter here.

Answer (score 3):

I expect that the author means that the statement that the rate of change of angular momentum about a point ${\bf R}$ is equal to the total torque about that point only if one of the following conditions are met

1. ${\bf R}$ is the center of mass
2. ${\bf R}$ is stationary (in an inertial frame)
3. $\frac{d {\bf R}}{dt}$ is parallel to the motion of the centre of mass.

For example see [Angular momentum conservation along translating axis of rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/549102/angular-momentum-conservation-along-translating-axis-of-rotation/549131#549131)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume a planar rotation around a fixed axis/point, we arrive at Newton's second law for rotation $\tau=I\alpha$ where the torque and moment of inertia are taken relative to that axis.

In deriving so, we assume a pure rotation around that point with the point staying stationary. For a general motion, we could boost to a frame that sees this point stationary (will be non-inertial in general) and use that equation. In doing so, we will see a fictitious force in that frame and the point of contact will be the CoM. That fictitious force doesn't cause a torque in that frame if the pivot is taken to be the CoM. In principle, we could use the above equation if we would include these additional apparent forces.

That is why in practice we prefer to decompose the motion into a translation of the CoM and a rotation around it so that the dynamics equations are straightforward.

If there is a stationary point (e.g. pendulum pivot), then using this point as the pivot will be much easier than the CoM and you get the equation of motion in a single shot (just by writing the rotation equation)

Answer (score 1):

The full vector form of the Newton-Euler equations of motion (translational and rotational) have their simplest form when the quantities are summed up at the center of mass.

Let us look at this in detail, designating the center of mass as point **C**. It is important to designate which points are quantities summed about in order to make the equations consistent. Just as you cannot equate $F = m a$ unless the acceleration describes the motion of the center of mass, so is  the full set of equations below:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{F} & = m\;\boldsymbol{a}_C \\
\boldsymbol{\tau}_C & = {\rm I}_C \,\boldsymbol{\alpha} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times {\rm I}_C\, \boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{aligned} \tag{1}$$

Where the net force $\boldsymbol{F}$, the rotational velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and rotational acceleration $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ are shared with the entire body and are not location specific. On the other hand, net torque $\boldsymbol{\tau}_C$, translational acceleration $\boldsymbol{a}_C$ and mass moment of inertia tensor ${\rm I}_C$, all are quantities that are evaluated at a specific location.

<sub>Here $\times$ is the vector cross product.</sub>

But now consider some other arbitrary point **A** and the transformation laws that allow us to evaluate quantities at different locations. Use the position
of **C** relative to **A** as the vector $\boldsymbol{c}$

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \boldsymbol{\tau}_A &= \boldsymbol{\tau}_C + \boldsymbol{c} \times \boldsymbol{F} \\
  \boldsymbol{a}_C &= \boldsymbol{a}_A + \boldsymbol{\alpha} \times \boldsymbol{c} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times ( \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{c}) \\
\end{aligned} \tag{2} $$

So the equations of motion as defined at an arbitrary point are

$$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{F} & =m\left(\boldsymbol{a}_{A}+\boldsymbol{\alpha}\times\boldsymbol{c}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times(\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{c})\right)\\
\boldsymbol{\tau}_{A} & ={\rm I}_{C}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times{\rm I}_{C}\,\boldsymbol{\omega}+\boldsymbol{c}\times\boldsymbol{F}
\end{aligned} \tag{3}$$

which are considerably more complex because they are no longer decoupled. Specifically, force $\boldsymbol{F}$ depends on the rotational acceleration $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, and torque $\boldsymbol{\tau}_A$ depends on the force $\boldsymbol{F}$.

The equations above can be decoupled somewhat to bring them to the general form of Newton-Euler equations of motion

$$ \begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{F} & =m\left(\boldsymbol{a}_{A}-\boldsymbol{c}\times\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times(\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{c})\right)\\
\boldsymbol{\tau}_{A} & =\boldsymbol{c}\times m\boldsymbol{a}_{A}+{\rm I}_{A}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times{\rm I}_{A}\,\boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{aligned} \tag{4}$$

where the mass moment of inertia at point **A** is evaluated using the parallel axis theorem ${\rm I}_A = {\rm I}_C + m \left( (\boldsymbol{c} \cdot \boldsymbol{c}) 1_{3×3} - \boldsymbol{c} \odot \boldsymbol{c} \right) $

<sub>where $\cdot$ is the vector dot product, and $\odot$ is the vector outer product, and $1_{3×3}$ is the identity matrix.</sub>

Equation (3) can be used if the motion is known, and the net force/torque needs to be evaluated.

To do the reverse, when the net force/torque is known and the motion is unknown use the following expression:

$$ \begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{a}_{A} & =\tfrac{1}{m}\boldsymbol{F}+\boldsymbol{c}\times\boldsymbol{\alpha}-\boldsymbol{\omega}\times(\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{c})\\
\boldsymbol{\alpha} & ={\rm I}_{C}^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{A}-\boldsymbol{c}\times\boldsymbol{F}-\boldsymbol{\omega}\times{\rm I}_{C}\,\boldsymbol{\omega}\right)
\end{aligned} \tag{5}$$